# CSS Table loses widths inside a div with fixed position

Tags: html, css

I have a complex `<table>` component that works as a Grid (called Grid) with dozen of subcomponents (buttons, tooltips, etc.). It has several features and my column widths are all set usign `min-width`.

The Grid works fine on any widths (100%, pixel based - 1000px, or 100vw).

Now I want to put that Grid in a modal frame:

```
.modal-frame {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 5%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; <=== IF I REMOVE THIS LINE GRID WORKS FINE
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.modal-frame-content {
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    border: 1px solid $ux-theme-color-border;;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.grid-content {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 5px;
}
```

The grid appears as follow:

```
<div class="modal-frame">
    <div class="modal-frame-content">
        <div class="grid-content">
           ... my grid component ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I put my grid on this modal frame, my table gets lost on its width, trying to stretch its coluns to fill the whole screen.

If I remove `width: 100%` on the modal-frame the grid apprears correct. I've also tried `left: 0` and `right: 0` with same problem.

What may be causing my Grid component to stretch in a wrong way and how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how `background: fixed` works first. When you use `width: 100%` in your `.modal-frame` selector, the width is not relative to its parent but to the **viewport**.

It's then logical that when you set `width: 100%` in your `.grid-content` selector, it tries to span across the whole page too.

Comment: Hum... What should be set then on `.grid-content`?

Comment: `.grid-content` is fine. But your `.modal-frame` should likely set its desired width in pixels (if its parent is 1000px wide, then set it to 1000px). If you want it to be dynamic `100% of my direct parent` you need to use javascript.